# Select box not retaining value

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have the following code to retain the value of a select box, which is submitting the form on change.

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="index.php" >
    <table width="98%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>SPAK Ref</td>
        <td><select name="SPKSelect" id="SPKSelect" onchange="document.forms[0].submit();document.forms['form2'].submit(); ">

                    <option value="">-- Select Ref --</option>
            <?php    

                $selectedSPK = $_POST['SPKSelect'];
                $assigned = $_POST['Sales_Exec'];
                $date = $_POST['DateSelect'];

                if ($selectedSPK);
                {
                    $SPKquery = "SELECT DISTINCT SPKCustNo FROM Data WHERE Assigned = '$assigned' AND RenewalDate = '$date' ORDER by RenewalDate";

                    $SPKresult = mysql_query($SPKquery);

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($SPKresult))
                    {
                        echo "<option value=\"".$row['SPKCustNo']."\">".$row['SPKCustNo']."</option>\n  ";
                    }

                }
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById('SPKSelect').value = <?php echo json_encode(trim($selectedSPK));?>;
            </script>
        </select>
```

And this isn't working, it just defaults back to the origianl --Select Ref--- option.

I have this exact code working for other selectboxes in `'form1'` however this is the first one in "form2' which sits next to form 1.  From what I can tell it's not retaining the `POST` value of `SPKSelect`.  Is this something to do with the fact that I'm using 2 forms?  Does POST only work on 1 form per page?  If so how can I get around this?

The full page is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>TIL / 006 Renewal Support Tool</title>
<link href="RenewalToolStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/functions.js"></script>

</head>

<?php

//Connect to Server / Database
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("TILRenewals");


function GenerateTable($Query)
{
    $host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "TILRenewals";
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());      //build MySQL Link
    mysql_select_db($db) or die('Could not select database');        //select database
    $Table = "";  //initialize table variable

    $Table.= "<table border='1' style=\"border-collapse: collapse; text-align: center; font-size: small; cellspacing: 10px; \">"; //Open HTML Table

    $Result = mysql_query($Query); //Execute the query
    if(mysql_error())
    {
        $Table.= "<tr><td>MySQL ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "</td></tr>";
    }
    else
    {
        //Header Row with Field Names
        $NumFields = mysql_num_fields($Result);
        $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000; text-align: center; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: medium;\">";
        for ($i=0; $i < $NumFields; $i++)
        {     
            $Table.= "<th>" . mysql_field_name($Result, $i) . "</th>"; 
        }
        $Table.= "</tr>";

        //Loop thru results
        $RowCt = 0; //Row Counter
        while($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result))
        {
            //Alternate colors for rows
            if($RowCt++ % 2 == 0) $Style = "background-color: #3D6522; color: #FFFFFF;";
            else $Style = "background-color: #FFFFFF; color:#3D6522;";

            $Table.= "<tr style=\"$Style\">";
            //Loop thru each field
            foreach($Row as $field => $value)
            {
                $Table.= "<td>$value</td>";
            }
            $Table.= "</tr>";
        }
       // $Table.= "<tr style=\"background-color: #000066; color: #FFFFFF;\"><td colspan='$NumFields'>Query Returned " . mysql_num_rows($Result) . " records</td></tr>";
    }
    $Table.= "</table>";

    return $Table;

}



?>





<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><img src="Images/Banner.png" width="728" height="90" /><!-- end .header --></div>
  <div class="content">
  <div id ="leftcolumn">
    <h2>View Assigned Cases</h2>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">



        <p>Sales Exec
          <select name="Sales_Exec" id="Sales_Exec" onchange="document.forms[0].submit();">

            <option value="">-- Select SE --</option>
            <?php    

$salesexec=$_POST['Sales_Exec'];

if ($salesexec);

{
    $Execquery = "SELECT DISTINCT Assigned FROM Data";

$Execresult = mysql_query($Execquery);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Execresult))
{
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['Assigned']."\">".$row['Assigned']."</option>\n  ";
}

}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('Sales_Exec').value = <?php echo json_encode(trim($_POST['Sales_Exec']));?>;
        </script>
          </select>
          Date
          <select name="DateSelect" id="DateSelect" onchange="document.forms[0].submit();">
            <option value="">-- Select Date --</option>
            <?php    

$selecteddate=$_POST['DateSelect'];

if ($selecteddate);

{
    $Datequery = "SELECT DISTINCT RenewalDate FROM Data ORDER by RenewalDate";

$Dateresult = mysql_query($Datequery);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Dateresult))
{
    echo "<option value=\"".$row['RenewalDate']."\">".$row['RenewalDate']."</option>\n  ";
}

}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('DateSelect').value = <?php echo json_encode(trim($_POST['DateSelect']));?>;
        </script>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>
          <?php

    $assigned = $_POST['Sales_Exec'];
    $date = $_POST['DateSelect'];
    echo GenerateTable("SELECT SPKCustNo, RenewalDate, Product, ForeName, Surname FROM Data WHERE Assigned = '$assigned' AND RenewalDate = '$date' ");

?>
        </p>
    </form>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
  <div id ="rightcolumn">
  <h2>View Individual Case</h2>
  <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="index.php" >
    <table width="98%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td>SPAK Ref</td>
        <td><select name="SPKSelect" id="SPKSelect" onchange="submit_form('form1'); submit_form('form2'); ">

                    <option value="">-- Select Ref --</option>
            <?php    

$selectedSPK = $_POST['SPKSelect'];
$assigned = $_POST['Sales_Exec'];
$date = $_POST['DateSelect'];


    $SPKquery = "SELECT DISTINCT SPKCustNo FROM Data WHERE Assigned = '$assigned' AND RenewalDate = '$date' ORDER by RenewalDate";

$SPKresult = mysql_query($SPKquery);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($SPKresult)) {

    if($row["SPKCustNo"] == $selectedSPK){

         $select_true = "selected='selected'";

    }

         print "<option " . $select_true . " value='" .$row["SPKCustNo"] . "'>" . $row["SPKCustNo"] . "</option>";

    }


?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('SPKselect').value = <?php echo json_encode(trim($_POST['SPKSelect']));?>;
        </script>    

        </select>
     </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="33%">ForeName</td>
        <td><select name="FName" id="FName">

          <option value="">--Customer ForeName---</option>
          <?php
                $assigned = $_POST['Sales_Exec'];
                $date = $_POST['DateSelect'];
                $selectedSPK = $_POST['SPKSelect'];

                if ($selectedSPK) {

                $FNamequery = "SELECT ForeName FROM Data WHERE  SPKCustNo = '$selectedCust'";

                $FNameresult = mysql_query($FNamequery);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($FNameresult))
                {
                    echo "<option value=\"".$row['ForeName']."\">".$row['ForeName']."</option>\n  ";
                }


                }


            ?>
          <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('FName').value = <?php echo json_encode(trim($_POST['FName']));?>;
            </script>



        </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </form>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>

  <!-- end .content --></div>

   <div class="footer">
    <p>Footer<img src="Images/TILLogo.png" width="150" height="79" /></p>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you see in `view source`?

Comment: @Mr.Alien - View source, shows the option is there, just not selected : <td><select name="SPKSelect" id="SPKSelect" onchange="document.forms['form1'].submit();document.forms['form2'].submit(); ">
        
                    <option value="">-- Select Ref --</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
  <script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('SPKSelect').value = "";
 </script>

Comment: `<select>` is not meant to submit a form - it is meant to select an option from a list. Use a properly list of links to jump to pages, or provide an OK button at least not to mess with user experience. Plus, intrusive JS is avoidable, as it is using `mysql_*` functions ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT EDIT:**

I have overlooked one big thing!

When you are submitting forms only the fields from current form are sent trough the request.

There is one workaround, you can have hidden fields in current form that corresponds to inputs from first form and use javascript on before submit to copy values from first form to current hidden elements. And then submit current form.

Possible error in onchange:

```
onchange="document.forms[0].submit();document.forms['form2'].submit(); "
```

Change it to:

```
onchange="document.forms['form2'].submit();"
```

And when you do an mysql_fetch do this so that you can know what is the current data so that you can select it, like this:

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($SPKresult)) {

    if($row["SPKCustNo"] == $selectedSPK){

         $select_true = "selected='selected'";

    }

         print "<option " . $select_true . " value='" .$row["SPKCustNo"] . "'>" . $row["SPKCustNo"] . "</option>";

    }
```

Also like Laurent said you need to remove semi colon from this line:

```
if ($selectedSPK);
{
```

it should look like this:

```
if ($selectedSPK) {
```

**EDIT JAVASCRIPT TIP:**

Create external .js file for example "workers.js" put it in for example js dir and include it in head of HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/workers.js"></script>
```

Then write your javascript functions in that file first function is this for submiting forms:

```
function submit_form(formid) {

    document.getElementById(formid).submit();

}
```

Then call it from HTML onchange like this:

```
onchange="submit_form('form_id');"
```

This is much cleaner method and longterm it will give you readable code.

Also try: http://www.smarty.net (for php templating)

Comment: I need to submit both forms at once onchange, which is why I included the first form, how can I get it to submit both at once?

Comment: You can call it like that, that is why I said possible error. But better write an javascript function for that because it is always better to have function instead of inline calling of script. Also I would strongly reccomend that you use some sort of template engine like smarty... If you need further help feel free to ask.

Comment: So I assume for a function, I just have that at the top of the page, simply duplicating the code I currently have in the on change? sorry about this, total noob, just trying to get this project working against a deadline

Comment: Got rid of the if statement totally, still defaults to top option, whilst, having the ACTUAL one in the list.  Wierd thing is, this code works perfectly on a different project, the only difference is here is that I'm using 2 forms.

Comment: I have heavily edited my answer to cover javascript reccomend part. Please give me a pastebin of whole page maybe you have some conflict in code aside of this that you have shown...

Comment: I'll edit the main question to show to the whole page, please forgive any poor coding / lack of best practise etc, as I said I'm a noob to this.  The Select Sales Exec and Renewal date parts work 100% fine in the first form, which you'll see are the same, just confused as to why this 2nd form doesn't work

Comment: Also try this http://yogendrakrsingh.blogspot.com/2010/03/javascript-trick-submitting-multiple.html

Comment: Could I stick form2 on a seperate page and display it using a frame?  I've tried the methods outlined in that blog, and whilst it NEARLY works...it doesn't.  Would a frame work? if not I'll have to do the second part on a new page.

Comment: I've worked out a different way of doing it using just 1 form / page, not ideal but gets the job done, thanks so much for your time and advice mate, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the following :

```
$date = $_POST['DateSelect'];

if ($selectedSPK); // The semi colon should not be there
{
```